# where clause does not work

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, where-clause

I am using visual studio2010, working with asp.net.
I want a query to work like example but mine doesn't work!

I have these rows in database:

```
Fullname=joe.address=earth,work=5656,home=23,mobile=55
Fullname=Michel.address=earth,work=5,home=2343,mobile=5435
```

User just enter:

```
Fullname=joe ,address=earth
```

The program should return JUST the first row.
0 is my default value for textBoxes.

```
SELECT fullName, address, work, home, mobile, registrationNo
  FROM contacts
 WHERE (fullName = @fullName OR fullName = '0')
   AND (address = @address OR address = '0')
   AND (work = @work OR work = '0')
   AND (home = @home OR home = '0')
   AND (mobile = @mobile OR mobile = '0')
```

Comment: well i think there is no need of parenthesis there in query ;)

Comment: Don't use '0' to mean no value.  You have `null` to do that.

Comment: Do you supply the values for every parameter listed above? Notice that if you set  Parameter.Value("@mobile", "0") your query  will not find any record

Comment: @AspiringAqib Parens are necessary here due to the `OR` conditions.

Comment: @JordanKaye well, i am related to php mysql! so, i thought it would be without brackets and in php mysql brackets are not necessary!

Comment: @PaulTomblin I used Null instead of zero too! but it does not give correct answer

Answer (score 6):

You're checking the *columns* to be equal to `'0'`, when I think you meant to check the parameters:

```
SELECT fullName, address, work, home, mobile, registrationNo
FROM   contacts
WHERE  (fullName = @fullName OR @fullName = '0')
AND    (address = @address   OR @address = '0')
AND    (work = @work         OR @work = '0')
AND    (home = @home         OR @home = '0')
AND    (mobile = @mobile     OR @mobile = '0')
```

As pointed out in the comments though, you really ought to use *`NULL`* for the absence of a value - that's the main reason it *exists* in SQL - and also means you can use appropriate data types (where necessary), rather than always treating things as strings. (In this case, however, everything does appear to be a string).

Comment: I got that point some seconds after I ask question! But in this way it does not work too!

Comment: You don't use '=' for null, you use `@fullName is null`

Comment: @PaulTomblin - I'm aware of this - however, in the posted example, I'm using the OPs `'0'` as the marker for "no value".

Comment: I was posting that for the benefit of the OP, who doesn't seem to have cracked open a tutorial on SQL.